# How can I make a function that contains mapped promises return a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have this AngularJS function:

```
topicsSave = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var defer = self.$q.defer();
    var requests = self.topics
        .map((rowData: any, i: number) => {
            var deferred = self.$q.defer();
            var entityId = rowData['topicId'];
            self.$http({ url: self.url,
                method: "PUT",
                data: rowData
            }).then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): void => {
                // 
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                }, (error: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): void => {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
            );
    self.$q.all(requests)
        .then(
            (): void => {
                self.topicsForm.$setPristine();
            },
            (): void => {
            });
}
```

From what I see $q.all returns a promise but how do I need to set up a nother defer variable and defer from that?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a deferred? Notice that using deferreds in conjunction with existing promises is referred to as [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: I am going through the rows of a datagrid and doing a save on each of these rows.  Each save has a completion promise. I use $q.all to wait until all those promises (saves) are completed okay and then I set the state of the grid to clean.  Note that I removed a few lines and replaced them with // to simplify this example.  The code doing the save seems to work okay but then I would like to make the topicsSave() function return a promise when it's completed. That's the bit I am unclear on right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```
topicsSave = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    ...
    return self.$q.all(requests)
    .then(
        (): void => {
            self.topicsForm.$setPristine();
        },
        (): void => {
            return $q.reject('$q.all rejection reason');
        });
}
```

Comment: Would I also need to return a $q.resolve after the self.topicsForm .. ?

Comment: No. The promise is already resolved. You may return the data that will be passed to next 'then', if needed. That's why deferreds are useless outside of jQuery.